# Can I fix choppy video shot at wrong shutter speed?

Tags: video, davinci-resolve, framerate, shutter

I shot some video at 60fps with the intention of putting it in a 24fps timeline slowed down. (59.97 and 23.976 actually) Usually I shoot at a shutter speed of 1/125 for shots like this. I shot some at 1/60 where it was too dark to shoot at 1/125. Between those two I really can't see a huge difference.

At some point however I must have bumped the shutter speed to 1/50. They don't look too different at full speed but when slowed down it seems a bit choppy. It's kind of a neat claymation style effect but not what I was going for. Was wondering if there was some way to smooth it out? I edit in Davinci Resolve

Comment: I wonder if you expose 1/125s for 60 FPS, I think you can *smooth* something, but when exposing 1/50s for 60 FPS, it should be *smooth* already.